# Expiration date check Mongodb | javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to check the expiration date of the purchased product and if the date is expired then I want to remove it.

The way I'm saving it to DB:

```
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let currentDateMiliseconds = currentDate.getTime();

  let courseExpiresMiliseconds =
    currentDateMiliseconds + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  // 90 Days validity
  let courseExpires = new Date(courseExpiresMiliseconds);

  let userPurchasedCourses = new usersPurchasedCourses({
    username: `${value_a}`,
    coursesList: JSON.parse(value_c.replaceAll(".", '"')),
    expirationDate: `courseExpires`,
    tran_date: tran_date,
    status: "VALID"
  });
  await userPurchasedCourses.save();
```

I'm getting the data:

```
let userCourses = await usersPurchasedCourses.find({
    $and: [{ username: req.body.username }, { status: "VALID" }],
   });
```

Here I want to have a list of only valid data. No expired ones. How may I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use greater than condition with current date using `$gt: new Date()`,

```
let userCourses = await usersPurchasedCourses.find({
  username: req.body.username,
  status: "VALID",
  expirationDate: { $gt: new Date() }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

moment.js worked well for me.

```
if(moment(new Date()).isSameOrAfter(new Date(item.expirationDate))){
        console.log("expired");
      } else {
        item.coursesList.map((item2) => {
          userallcourses.push(item2);
        });
      }
```

Comment: this is not the right solution, because you are filtering after retrieving all the documents, which means you are querying all the documents and filtering on the server side. it will impact on retriving speed because ex: you collection have 100 documents and there are 2 documents that are not expired and you need that only, but you query will return 100 documents.